# Express 4 - REST-Client gets 404 for route with an asynchronous handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

**EDIT 2 - FIXED**

I just reinstalled express freshly in my project folder and it worked. Then after some seconds it stopped working.

I'm using Webstorm and have a babel file watcher for ES6 files. That file watcher kicks in when installing a node module and seems to mess up the module code somehow.

I set a specific scope for the file watcher. I use *.es6 for my ES6-Code files. Now all is fine.

**Original question**

So I have the simplest thing in express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.route("/test").get(function (req, res) {
    console.log(res.headersSent);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(res.headersSent);
        try {
            res.send("done waiting");
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e.stack);
        }
    }, 1000);
});

app.use("/", router);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I run the server and make a GET request to localhost:3000/test

I get a 404 immediately. And the console says

```
App listening at http://:::3000
false
true
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:350:11)
```

So the `false` indicates headers weren't sent before my handler was invoked.

The `true` comes up after 1000ms. It indicates headers were sent before my async function was invoked.

I expected my REST-client (Postman in that case) to hang on to it's request for 1000 ms, get the response and display "done waiting"

My understanding is that somewhere a 404 for that route was sent because my handler didn't do the response right away.

I'm sure I miss something really stupid, but I searched the internet back and forth for half a day, read tutorials and cannot find a solution.

I used express before (v2 and v3) sporadically and did asynchronous things in request handlers. Never had that problem.

So, what am I missing here?

nodejs is 4.2.1
Express is 4.13.3

**EDIT 1**

I'm on Windows 7, 64 bit, node is 64 bit as well.

I tested this on another computer (OS X) and it works just fine. I'm clueless. I searched for other versions of express globally installed but there seems to be nothing. I tried other ports, to no avail.

Comment: are you sure  that are the right versions?  i copy and paste your code, and all works , without any problem. i'm using the same versions that you describe above.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Just checked again. I'm on Win 7 64 bit, nodejs is 64 bit as well

Comment: node 4.1.2, under Windows 10/OS X 10.11, all behave normally.